# How to obtain typeface for RobotoTextView from reference styleable attribute

Tags: android, styles, declare-styleable

I have a custom view which contains several RobotoTextViews and I want to set typefaces for them.
So, I use declare-styleable item like this:

```
<declare-styleable name="CustomView">
        <attr name="firstTextviewStyle" format="reference" />
        <attr name="secondTextviewStyle" format="reference" />
</declare-styleable>
```

The attributes are referenced to styles.

```
<style name="firstTextAppearance">
        <item name="typeface">roboto_medium</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

So, question is, how to get typeface attr value from this?

Comment: it's not possible whatever you described need more explanation.@nullpex what do you wanna try to achieve by doing this maybe there is a simple way

Comment: @Harsh Sharma, goal is next: set RobotoTextView style while inflating CustomView. I use TypedArray for getting this, but I can't obtain typeface attr from style.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**@nullpex** you can do something like this for dynamic or runtime font change in your app like the following example. You can also use it in your layout file cuz there is custom view also with custom attributes.

I have created a repository for the following code on GitHub
https://github.com/harsh159357/customtextview

Feel free to ask any question

**CustomTextViewActivity.java**

```
package com.harsh.customtextview;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class CustomTextViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    CustomTextView customTextView1, customTextView2;
    Button changeToRoboto, changeToCalculus;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_text_view);

        customTextView1 = (CustomTextView) findViewById(R.id.customTextView1);
        customTextView2 = (CustomTextView) findViewById(R.id.customTextView2);

        changeToRoboto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.change_to_roboto);
        changeToCalculus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.change_to_calculus);
        changeToRoboto.setOnClickListener(this);
        changeToCalculus.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.change_to_roboto:
                customTextView1.setFont(getString(R.string.font_roboto_regular));
                customTextView2.setFont(getString(R.string.font_roboto_regular));
                break;
            case R.id.change_to_calculus:
                customTextView1.setFont(getString(R.string.font_calculus_sans));
                customTextView2.setFont(getString(R.string.font_calculus_sans));
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_text_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.harsh.customtextview.CustomTextViewActivity">

    <com.harsh.customtextview.CustomTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/themed_text"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        app:theme="@style/roboto_theme"/>

    <com.harsh.customtextview.CustomTextView
        android:id="@+id/customTextView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/calculus_sans"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        app:fonts="@string/font_calculus_sans" />

    <com.harsh.customtextview.CustomTextView
        android:id="@+id/customTextView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/roboto_regular"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:fonts="@string/font_roboto_regular" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/change_to_roboto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Change to Roboto" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/change_to_calculus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Change to Calculus" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**CustomTextView.java**

```
package com.harsh.customtextview;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;

@SuppressLint("AppCompatCustomView")
public class CustomTextView extends TextView {

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init(attrs);
    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(attrs);
    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(attrs);
    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(null);
    }

    private void init(AttributeSet attrs) {
        if (attrs != null) {
            TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomView);
            String fontName = a.getString(R.styleable.CustomView_fonts);

            try {
                if (fontName != null) {
                    Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/" + fontName);
                    setTypeface(myTypeface);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            a.recycle();
        }
    }

    public void setFont(String fontName) {
        setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/" + fontName));
    }
}
```

**attrs.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="CustomView">
        <attr name="fonts" format="string" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>


<style name="roboto_theme">
    <item name="font">@string/font_calculus_sans</item>
</style>
```

**strings.xml**

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">CustomTextView</string>
    <string name="font_calculus_sans">Calculus_Sans.ttf</string>
    <string name="font_roboto_regular">Roboto_Regular.ttf</string>
    <string name="calculus_sans">Calculus Sans</string>
    <string name="roboto_regular">Roboto Regular</string>
    <string name="themed_text">Themed Text</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: font in layout file and predefined font attribute are collapsing and when i changed it to fontName in attr file getting another error: cannot find symbol variable CustomView_font. Please respond

Comment: @GaneshChowdharySadanala, If you have changed it to "fontName" in attr file then you must look for "CustomView_fontName" instead of "CustomView_font"